# HTML/JS Multiple Pie Chart Issue

Tags: javascript, html, pie-chart

- I am facing problem in getting multiple pie chart on my webpage.
- I got it from codepen, when i tried to implement more than one Pei chart in a page, it displayed errors in chart.
- **Please check Codepen Link after Screenshots**

Screenshots below :

**Single Pie Chart - No problems**

[image]

***On addition of another chart, there are these data-set loading problems, it shows 5 fields in each chart instead of 3 and 2 respectively***
[image]

> [LINK to codepen](https://codepen.io/KrupeshAnadkat/pen/wEeKRd?editors=1000)

HTML Code (*please click Above Link for CSS & JS Code*)

```
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="pieID pie"></div>
    <ul class="pieID legend">
      <li><em>Humans</em><span>718</span></li>
      <li><em>Dogs</em><span>531</span></li>
      <li><em>Cats</em><span>868</span></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
<!--  Un-commenting Below brings erro in first pie chart, how can i get to charts on same page? Thanks -->
  <section>
    <div class="pieID pie"></div>
    <ul class="pieID legend">
      <li><em>Slugs</em><span>344</span></li>
      <li><em>Aliens</em><span>1145</span></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Spent Hours figuring Out Solution, but couldnt. I want to use Pie chart which has legend and Chart, no interaction with chart required. Constraints : Pie chart dataset must be from html file and Multiple charts can be created in single page. **Anyhelp is Appreciated**

Comment: because, its adding  class="pieID legend" to class="pieID pie" again, so you need to rename this classes

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan Could you please Show the Same in code, i have tried what you said and it didnt work, Thankyou

Comment: check Liko answer

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan I was wondering if i can change colors on 2nd pie chart. is it possible with the present js code?I know they are coming from color array of js. Thanks

Comment: yes, check var color code on js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179406/discussion-between-krupesh-anadkat-and-shanu-t-thankachan).

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan I have posted code and image and what all i did, in chat link, before this i never knew stackoverflow has chat feature , lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right, just remember to use unique identifiers for your elements 
Add ids for your elements:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="pieID pie" id="pie1"></div>
    <ul class="pieID legend" id="legend1">
      <li><em>Humans</em><span>718</span></li>
      <li><em>Dogs</em><span>531</span></li>
      <li><em>Cats</em><span>868</span></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
<section>
    <div class="pieID pie" id="pie2"></div>
    <ul class="pieID legend" id="legend2">
      <li><em>Slugs</em><span>344</span></li>
      <li><em>Aliens</em><span>1145</span></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

Call the creation function like

```
createPie("#legend1", "#pie1");
createPie("#legend2", "#pie2");
```